# Xamarin Forms issue with HTTPS request

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created an application in **Xamarin forms** with **Visual Studio 2017 Professional** and **Visual Studio 2019 cumulative** edition.

The problem is that the app works fine with HTTP requests, but in the case of an **HTTPS** request I have got time out every time with **Visual Studio 2017** & with **Visual Studio 2019** I have observed sometimes getting response of request and sometimes app not able to hit **HTTPS** request.

I have same code to call API.
I am able to post **WEB API** with **Postman** every time successfully.

```
            HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unused;
            HttpStatusCodeDescription = String.Empty;

            var response = default(TResp);
            XStatusCode = null;
            
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;

            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mServiceUrl + serviceName);
           
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password)));
           
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

           

            var reqData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));

            webRequest.ContentLength = reqData.Length;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
             using (var reqStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                reqStream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);

            try
            {
                using (webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (typeof(TResp) != typeof(object))
                    {
                        using (var respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            var reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResp>(result);
                        }
                    }

                    HttpStatusCode = webResponse.StatusCode;
                    HttpStatusCodeDescription = webResponse.StatusDescription;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (webResponse != null)
                {
                    HttpStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusCode;
                    HttpStatusCodeDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusDescription;
                    if (webResponse.Headers["X-StatusCode"] != null)
                    {
                        XStatusCode = int.Parse(webResponse.Headers["X-StatusCode"]);
                        if (webResponse.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            if (typeof(TResp) != typeof(object))
                            {
                                using (var respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                {
                                    var reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                    response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResp>(result);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    webResponse.Close();
                }
            }
           
            return response;
```

Tried with Http Client also getting same result

```
HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unused;
            HttpStatusCodeDescription = String.Empty;

            var result = default(TResp);
            XStatusCode = null;
           



            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password)));

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                var response = await client.PostAsync(mServiceUrl + serviceName, content);
              

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResp>(response.Content.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (webResponse != null)
                {
                    HttpStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusCode;
                    HttpStatusCodeDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusDescription;
                    if (webResponse.Headers["X-StatusCode"] != null)
                    {
                        XStatusCode = int.Parse(webResponse.Headers["X-StatusCode"]);
                        if (webResponse.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            if (typeof(TResp) != typeof(object))
                            {
                                using (var respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                {
                                    var reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                                    string resulttmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResp>(resulttmp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    webResponse.Close();
                }
            }
            


            return result;
```

PCL Package are :-
[PCL Nuget packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juYoj.jpg)
and
[Android installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cntPv.jpg)

After adding below line

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
```

Post request working fine but still getting problem with Get Request

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password)));
                    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0;
                    System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
                    string url = mServiceUrl + serviceName;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

                    /// var response = await client.GetStringAsync(serviceName);
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResp>(response);

                    //if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    //{

                    //    using (HttpContent _content = response.Content)
                    //    {
                    //        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResp>(await _content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    //    }

                    //}
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                    if (webResponse != null)
                    {
                        HttpStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusCode;
                        HttpStatusCodeDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusDescription;
                        if (webResponse.Headers["X-StatusCode"] != null)
                        {
                            XStatusCode = int.Parse(webResponse.Headers["X-StatusCode"]);
                            if (webResponse.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                if (typeof(TResp) != typeof(object))
                                {
                                    using (var respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                    {
                                        var reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                                        string resulttmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResp>(resulttmp);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        webResponse.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have found two issue in android app.

1. Network config file missing.
2. Missing DNS record entry.

But now Android App side every thing working fine. But getting same problem at IOS Side not able to hit HTTPS Request.

Comment: You can share your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: But problem are still unsolved.

Comment: You still get time out when perform Get request?

Comment: yes, not getting any response from api side, where as api return json string, but i am getting timeout at mobile app end. Request reached at web server, but at mobile side getting timeout.

Comment: So that means the sever side does not response the request? Did you try the api with some tools like fiddler to see if it works?

Comment: yes i have tried with postman, Advance RESET client everything is working fine.

Comment: After done some changes at DNS server side and again attach fiddler (via wifi proxy setting) now getting app able to hit each and every request and when i close fiddler again getting same problem even post and get both request not working getting timeout.

Answer (score 0):

### DNS cache timeout

Are you using a domain name that's translated to a different ip address on your network than when using 4G?

I once had a similar issue when switching from wifi to 4g. In an android app, the dns lookup is by default cached for 2 minutes (120000 milliseconds) causing the webrequest to still use the local ip while connected to 4g.

I solved this by setting the `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0` in the android project

### Self-signed certificate

Another possibility is that you're using a self-signed certificate. Self-signed certificates are by default rejected by Xamarin.Android. You could get around this by assigning the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to a func where you check if the certificate-signature complies with the self-signed certificate, or always return true (not recommended).

Now according to [this post](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3682#issuecomment-535679023) it's not recommended to assign this static func field, but instead use a custom HttpClientHandler where you override the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` method.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    // Change the func to check if the correct certificate is provided
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate, chain, errors) => true
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

You have to copy-paste the code. For some reason IntelliSense does not provide suggestions for the member `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`.

Comment: Yes i have used a domain name that translated to a different address.

Comment: Does setting the dns cache timeout in the android project solve the issue? Are you using a self signed SSL certificate? Android rejects self-signed ssl certificates by defalt but you can solve this easily

Comment: No i have used go dady signed trusted certificate, after adding  dnsrefreshtimeout first time installed app getting timeout for sometime after than it works fine. Thanks for help

Comment: Updated my question after adding two lines and getting issue with get request.